# Best way to relate the order ID with the products that belongs to it

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm developing a shop system and I'm using the only method I was able to find to relate the ID of the order with the products that belongs to it.
When someone purchase something, first the order is added to the table `orders` with their details, including the ID of that order (`order_id`), that is auto incremented by the SQL.
I use this to add an order to the table `orders`:

```
INSERT INTO orders SET customer_id = '{$customer_id}', customer_name = '{$user['customer_name']}', order_price = '{$total_price}', order_date = '{$date}'"
```

Ok, the order was added. Now, in sequence, the products that belongs to that order will be added to another table, the table `purchased_products`.
I use PDO `lastInsertId()` to get the last inserted `order_id` from the table `orders` and then add each product of that order with a `Foreign Key` `order_id` in another table called `purchased_products`. To do this, I use:

```
$respective_order_id = $connection->lastInsertId();

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO purchased_products SET order_id = '{$respective_order_id}', product_name = '{$product['product_name']}', product_price = '{$product['product_price']}', quantity = '{$product['quantity']}'";
}
```

These codes run simultaneously. First the order will be added in the `orders` table with their `order_id` auto incremented, and then all the products of that order will also be added to the `purchased_products` table and the `Foreign Key` `order_id` of each one of them will have the value of the last `order_id` inserted in the `orders` table. Later I will can display any order with their products by consulting it with the Foreign Key `order_id`.
So far, it's working well. And as I said, this was the only way I found to assign the ID of the order with the products that belongs to it. My question is: is this secure? How about if several people buy the same time? There is the risk of the IDs be exchanged or the products not added/or goes to the wrong order? I would be immensely grateful if someone experienced answer these questions because this is making me afraid, I'm wondering if I can trust in this method.
**EDIT**
More details!
My database connection:

```
try
{
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host={$HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}", $USERNAME, $PASS);
}

catch(PDOException $exception)
{
    echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

All the code I use to insert the data in the two tables:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders SET customer_id = '{$customer_id}', customer_name = '{$user['customer_name']}', order_price = '{$total_price}', order_date = '{$date}'"

$query = $connection->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

$respective_order_id = $connection->lastInsertId();

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO purchased_products SET order_id = '{$respective_order_id}', product_name = '{$product['product_name']}', product_price = '{$product['product_price']}', quantity = '{$product['quantity']}'";

    $query = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
}
```

**EDIT 2 UPDATE**
Some products can have extra arrays, (i.e. colour) and some not. But all by default have these arrays filled: `product_name`, `product_price` and `product_quantity`.
I've adapted my logic to check for extra parameters with the code provided by **peterm**:

```
$connection->beginTransaction();

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, customer_name, order_price, order_date) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$query = $connection->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array
(
    $customer_id, 
    $user['customer_name'], 
    $total_price, 
    $date
));

$respective_order_id = $connection->lastInsertId();

$sql = "INSERT INTO purchased_products (order_id, product_name, product_price, quantity, colour) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

$query = $connection->prepare($sql);

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product)
{
    $additional_param = array
    (
        'colour' => NULL
    );

    $colour = array_filter($product['colour']);

    if(!empty($colour))
    {
        $additional_param['colour'] = $product['colour']['colour_name'];
    }

    $query->execute(array
    (
        $respective_order_id,
        $product['product_name'],
        $product['product_price'],
        $product['quantity'],
        $additional_param['colour']
    ));
}
$connection->commit();
```

If the extra parameter array in the SESSION is not null, then the `colour` key in the SQL table will be filled with the product colour. Otherwise, it will be filled with SQL `NULL`.

Comment: I haven't used PHP in over a decade, but just on pure gut instinct: unless it was part of a transaction, I would not trust `lastInsertId()` to infallibly get me the correct `order_id`.  Think about what might happen if another order (or any other record, potentially) happens to be inserted during the time between the original insertion to `order` and the call to `lastInsertId`.

Comment: @PaulGriffin Thanks for the comment. I want to make a comparison of opinions and reach a solid conclusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using PDO's `lastInsertId()`, is driver dependent, but safe to use as long as you're using a proper auto incrementing type of object (i.e. `AUTO_INCREMENT` in MySQL or sequence in PostgreSQL). MySQL driver uses [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) under the hood.
2. If you care about transactional integrity consider wrapping the whole operation into a transaction. That way it's either all properly committed or rolled back. No orphaned order header rows, no partially populated orders etc.
3. Since you're using PDO **stop** doing query string interpolation. Learn and make use of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
4. Once you start using prepared statements you'll not only make things much secure but can speed up your inserts for order detail's rows.

---

> Yes, I use AUTO_INCREMENT and also prepare in all insertions before execute: $query = $connection->prepare($sql); $query->execute(); I just don't understood your second explanation.

What you're currently doing is useless and dangerous. You're concatenating the query with the the values (there is nothing to prepare in your case so to speak)  instead of using placeholders in the query and then binding values.

**UPDATED:** Here is how your may look like

```php
$colour = array_filter($product['colour']);

$connection->beginTransaction(); // Turn off auto commit and explicitly open transaction

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, customer_name, order_price, order_date) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?)"; // Use placeholders in the query. You can use named placeholders if you want to
$query = $connection->prepare($sql); // Prepare the statement
$query->execute(array(
    $customer_id, 
    $user['customer_name'], 
    $total_price, 
    $date)
); // Bind the values and execute the statement

$respective_order_id = $connection->lastInsertId();

$sql = "INSERT INTO purchased_products (order_id, product_name, product_price, quantity, colour) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
$query = $connection->prepare($sql); // Prepare once !!!

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product) {
    $query->execute(array(
        $respective_order_id,
        $product['product_name'],
        $product['product_price'],
        $product['quantity'],
        empty($colour) ? null : $product['colour']['colour_name'], //you can bind null value for nullable columns
    )); // Bind and execute multiple times
}
// Explicitly commit the transaction
$connection->commit();
```

Comment: Yes, I use `AUTO_INCREMENT` and also `prepare` in all insertions before execute: `$query = $connection->prepare($sql); 
  $query->execute();`
I just don't understood your second explanation. I've edited my question and inserted the code that I'm actually using to insert the data in both tables. Please take a look!

Comment: @Dyan Did it help in any way?

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to adapt your code here, but I'm facing a single little problem. I've updated the question. Please see my **EDIT 2** to understand. Thank you for the assistence!

Comment: @Dyan In all fairness your follow up question is out the scope of your original question. That being said, you can either continue using `SET` syntax, use placeholders in the query, and keep track of bindings adding them to array, or you can include all your nullable columns in your query and just bind null values. See updated code in my answer

Comment: I've found a logic to adapt to your code that is working as I want. Please take a look in my **EDIT 2 UPDATE**

Comment: Your answer was helpful even from the beginning. I was just waiting for reach a conclusion that you agree to accept the answer. Thank you for correcting my faults. Certainly my question and your answer will be useful to the community and will help a lot of people! Thank you for taking your time to help me, a big hug! :)